# Embedding Vaadin (version 24) UIs in Web Pages

Tags: vaadin

This page describes how Vaadin components can be embedded in web pages:
https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/advanced/advanced-embedding

I have used this approach to embed my Vaadin components into Thymeleaf templates. Now I have to migrate to Vaadin 24 and need a solution for embedding. VAADIN/vaadinBootstrap.js does not exist anymore and I don't find any relevant documentation. Please help!

Comment: This section in the documentation should help you: https://vaadin.com/docs/integrations/embedding

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Vaadin 14, how do I embedd my Vaadin page inside another web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67414997/in-vaadin-14-how-do-i-embedd-my-vaadin-page-inside-another-web-page)